# How would I setup github actions for a flutter project in a subdirectory

Tags: flutter, github-actions, subdirectory

I am working on github actions for ci/cd in flutter. The code is a subdirectory to the main repository folder. How would I run the github action in the subdirectory.

I am making use of the [subosito flutter action](https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action)

```
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter test
      - run: flutter build appbundle
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

[`run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) accepts a keyword named `working-directory`. Just set it to the subdirectory and you're good to go. It's going to be something like this:

```yaml
      - run: flutter pub get
        working-directory: your_subdirectory
      - run: flutter test
        working-directory: your_subdirectory
      - run: flutter build appbundle
        working-directory: your_subdirectory
```

### Solution 2

It's also possible to set it per job ([jobs.<job_id>.defaults.run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun)) like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: your_subdirectory
```

### Solution 3

You can also use [`defaults.run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun) to set the default directory globally (for all jobs) as the subdirectory you expect. This way you'd remove a lot of repetition.

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: your_subdirectory
```